# Can not established a connection to jdbc with Hibernate-SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

I made a connection to SQL server with Hibernate configuration wizard, when I click test connection, I get success message, but when I want to make hibernate mapping, I cannot I get error message, Cannot established a connection to jdbc.  The below code is jdbc connection with hibernate; please say me, what is the problem?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
<property   name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property     name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">sa123</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Please paste the logs

Comment: when i want to make mapping in new hibernate mapping->select mapping class, I get error: "unable to connect. can not establish a connection to jdbc"

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your code i found you did not specify the port number for database connection

```
<property     name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Test</property>
```

There should be a port number if your trying to connect on your local machine for an example please refer following line

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=syv</property>
```

Please check and let me know ...if there is any further issue

Ok here i am sending you the basic hibernate configuration : -

**STEP 1 :-** **Create a Java File “AddStudent” and paste the below code into that.**

```
//package code;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class AddStudent {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER YOUR NAME");
        String name = d.readLine();
        System.out.println("ENTER YOUR DEGREE");
        String degree = d.readLine();
        System.out.println("ENTER YOUR PHONE");
        String phone = d.readLine();
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
        System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);
        if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals("") || phone.equals(""))) {
            System.out.println("All informations are Required");
        } else {
            try {
                // begin try
                sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                        .buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."
                        + e);
            }
            Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            Student stu = new Student();
            stu.setName(name);
            stu.setDegree(degree);
            stu.setPhone(phone);
            s.save(stu);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Added to Database");
            if (s != null)
                s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**STEP 2 : Create a Java File “Student” paste the below code into that.**

```
//package code;
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String degree;
    private String phone;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setId(long string) {
        id = string;
    }

    public void setName(String string) {
        name = string;
    }

    public void setDegree(String string) {
        degree = string;
    }

    public void setPhone(String string) {
        phone = string;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Create an xml file “hibernate.cfg.xml” place the below code into that.**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="studentFactory">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">
            system
        </property>
        <property name="connection.password">
            system
        </property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
            </property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <mapping resource="Student.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Step 4:Create an xml File “student.hbm.xml” and place below code into that.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="Student" table="Stutbl" >
         <id name="id" type="long" column ="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
         </id>
         <property name="name" column="name" not-null="true"/>
         <property name="degree" column="degree" />
         <property name="phone" column="phone" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Step 5: Add the required jar to your project**

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Did you included the correct jdbc.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder so that your application would be able to make connection with database

Comment: thank you, my application is java application, i add jar file "sqljdbc4.jar" to my project.

Comment: Please post the exceptions logs which you are getting while running your application...

Comment: when i want to make mapping in new hibernate mapping->select mapping class, I get error: "unable to connect. can not establish a connection to jdbc"

Comment: Are you using any plugin to create mapping with the class?

Comment: I  use Hibernate mapping wizard in net-beans for creating hibernate-mapping.

Comment: I would suggest to do it manually. You can post the Entity class and hibernate mapping file i will help to map you..

Comment: Thank you, i have a Entity, Entity name is Role_T, it has tow columns,the first ID and the second is RoleName_nvc, i made hbm, the below code is for hbm file:                             <hibernate-mapping>
    
   <class name="Entity.Role_T" table="Role_T">
     <id column="id" name="id"/>
     <property column="RoleName_nvc" name="RoleName_nvc"/>
   </class>
  
 </hibernate-mapping>
the name of hbm file is Role_T.hbm, when i run the program  for read data from role_t i get the error of "/hibernate.cfg.xml not found".

Comment: For your reference i have posted a step wise tutorial to create a simple hibernate project without using any plugin.....so just go through it and create the similar one .....it will definitely solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, i put this code in my project but i take the error: "/hibernate.cfg.xml not found", i changed file "hibernate.cfg"  , because you used oracle, but i wan to use sql server, but when i run project i get that error: "/hibernate.cfg.xml not found".

Comment: Hibernate XML configuration file “hibernate.cfg.xml” is always put at the root of your project classpath, outside of any package. If you place this configuration file into a different directory, you may encounter the following error :"/hibernate.cfg.xml not found"

Comment: thank you,i add to default package but i can not make sessionFactory, this  line i take below error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
 at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:96)
 at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1385)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
 at testhibernate1.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:40)

Comment: The javax.persistence.Entity is a class inside the J2EE SDK library “javaee.jar“, you are missing this jar file in your project classpath.

Comment: thank you fro your helping, that error solved with your suggestion but i get new error:                                                                 "Could not parse mapping document from resource Student.hbm.xml"

Comment: Please check in your hibernate.cfg.xml that you have included Student.hbm.xml or not. If you have included than did you included twice or not...its basically configuration exception you are getting just check all the configuration once and than run

Comment: thank you, I have problem yet, hibernate.cfg.xml includes Student.hbm.xml

Comment: <session-factory >
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ACM</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sa123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

Comment: <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
     <property name="show_sql">false</property>
     <mapping resource="student.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>

Answer (score -1):

Add this:

```
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

and verify if your Database accept connections.